# xampp apache port error?

Tags: apache, vhosts

In my `httpd.config` I use this

```
Listen 80
Listen 8079

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\...\wwwroot"
    ServerName testing-website.nl
    <Directory "D:\...\wwwroot">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8079>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-developer"
    ServerName wp-developer-test.dev
        <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-developer">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hostfile is also updated to `127.0.0.1 wp-developer-test.dev`

But when I use `wp-developer-test.dev` or `wp-developer-test.dev:8079` in my browser, I get the `testing-website.nl` website instead. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a different servername in a hosts file and in Virtual host configuration.
Fix the host file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 wp-developer-test.dev
```

**Explanation:**
The first defined virtual host is used as a default one. It means that when request does not match any virtual host the first one is used.

Comment: edit: I still get redirected to the testing-website.nl